# How to format decimals in Thymeleaf without unnecessary zeros

Tags: spring, spring-boot, formatting, decimal, thymeleaf

I have a problem with decimals in Thymeleaf. In my app I store the amount of coins in a variable of type Double and when I try to render it in thymeleaf view I receive scientific notation.

In the Thymeleaf documentation I found a method called formatDecimal but in my case it doesn't work as I want to.

**EXAMPLE:**

***In my Thymeleaf template:***

`<td th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(coin.getAmountOfCoin(), 1, 8)}">`

***In browser:***

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKaJe.png)

Is there any possibility to remove unnecessary zeros?